What order/arrangement for these lights and switch?
I live in western New York. My basement is usable space; it is by no means considered livable by real estate rules.
In my basement the main circuit breaker box is on the north wall. The only light switch for the basement is at the top of the stairs at the south end of the basement. Three of the five light fixtures (NW, SW, NE) currently in the basement are being used as pass-through hubs to help distribute power all over the house. The five lights that I want to be controlled by the single switch are at, roughly the NW, SW, NE, SE, and S locations, so if I could turn them all on at the same time then the whole basement would have light.
The switch is about 32 feet horizontally and 5 feet vertically from the main box. It is at the top of the stairs so that someone can turn on the light before they go downstairs.
The S light is already a bar light; at one point somebody cut off the plug end of the cord and wired it straight to the electricity. I have two other bar lights with their plugs intact. I could easily get two more.
So my main question is - Given that layout, what is a safe and maintainable way to change up the wiring so that the one switch will turn on all of the lights?
I can think of a lot of possible (though not necessarily proper or safe) ways to do it.
Should I wire from the box to the switch first (so 40ish feet of 14/2 along the ceiling and through the floor), from the switch to a central "hub" box in the middle of the basement ceiling, and then from there to each of the five lights?
Like this?

Or is there another way that is safer and more maintainable?

Usually you want to use the shortest distance between lights/outlets.  A centre point might use more wire that from light to light

You mention five light fixtures. It's unclear from your post how many light fixtures the switch currently controls? 1, 2 or 3?

There is no need to run a separate circuit from the main to the switch, unless that circuit is at capacity. If it's not at capacity simply continue your wiring from J-box to J-box.

HoneyDo, The light switch currently turns on only the S light. Nothing else. No other lights or outlets. To your other question - I'm also trying to change the wiring so that I can turn on and off different rooms./areas. Right now that one circuit handles parts of the basement, kitchen, bathroom, and dining rooms and one of the bedrooms.

As I mentioned in my comment, there isn't a need to run a separate circuit from the main unless the switched circuit is at capacity or if you need a neutral in the switch box for a smart switch. If that's not the case then adding a few lights should be fine.
I think from your post that only the S light is currently operated by the switch. From the S light you can run either a 14/2 or 12/2 with ground (depending on 15 or 20 amp circuit) from the S light in series to each of the others. You want to be sure to carry the neutral along with the switched hot in the same circuit from the S light to each of the other switched lights that you add.
Edit:   I just saw your comment about the light switch circuit. It sounds as if there's a lot on that circuit, Assuming it's 20 amp it can handle 1920 watts safely. Depending on what is already on it you may want to run a separate circuit for the basement lights. In that case you can run 12/2 NM w/grd on a new 20 amp circuit from the panel to the switch. This will also provide a neutral in the switch box in case someone wants to add a smart switch later.
I'm not an electrician but I'm sure one of the pros will help fine-tune my answer if needed.
